# GwtUploader - Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gwt, gwtupload

In my webapp I'am use GWT and I want to use GwtUploader. Problem is that i can't @Autowire any services into my class that handle request. Propably becouse it's not spring component but i don`t have any idea how to solve problem.

Here is my config:

Servlet:

```
@Component("gwtUploadServlet")
public class GwtUploadServlet extends UploadAction {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    SomeService .....;

    public String executeAction(HttpServletRequest request,
        List<FileItem> sessionFiles) {

        .....
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gwtUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>xxx.gwtUploader.GwtUploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gwtUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bbsapp/fileUpload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am using services in many places and they're working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved problem adding:

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);

    // a workaround for forcing this servlet to autowire its components
    WebApplicationContext webAppCtx = WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
    webAppCtx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
}
```

And now I have problem with session. When i try to use services i get:

```
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.userSessionService': Scope 'session' 
is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this 
bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to 
request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside 
of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web 
request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside 
of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener 
or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```